# Discord.js bot counting specific word per user

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that counts a specific word per user
My bot is in version 12 discord.js. I really don't know how to do this.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're trying to count how many times a certain word has been mentioned in a message?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to count how many times the user used "x" word in his message. Here are the steps:

1. Get all the words the user typed into an array:

> const args = message.content.slice("!").trim().split(/ +/);

Now, you have an array with all words the user has typed in his message. The "!" in the code is the prefix. You will have to ignore the prefix and not add that into the array.

2. Loop through the array to find the word

```js
c = 0
args.forEach(word => {
    if (word.includes("hi")) c++;
});
```

Here, `c = 0` which increases whenever the `word == "hi"`.

Comment: Simpler method: `args.filter(arg => arg === 'hi').length`